# Cannot resolve symbol 'FirebaseListAdapter'

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Found a problem while trying to make **FirebaseListAdapter** for my **ListView**, which I want to populate from Firebase Real-time Database.
Android Studio says `Cannot resolve symbol 'FirebaseListAdapter'`, when im focusing `FirebaseListAdapter<Trick> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Trick>(options){}`. Same with `FirebaseListOptions<Trick> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<Trick>(){}`

Made all changes from a dublicated question, including updating **build.gradle**, but nothing helps

My project's **build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My app's **build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "cz.zelgadiss.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.GwonHyeok:StickySwitch:0.0.15'
    implementation 'com.github.medyo:fancybuttons:1.9.1'

}
```

My **code**:

```
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class EncyActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {


    ListView list_View;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ency);

        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Tricks");
        list_View = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        FirebaseListOptions<Trick> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<Trick>()
                .setLayout(R.layout.trick)
                .setQuery(query, Trick.class)
                .build();

        FirebaseListAdapter<Trick> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Trick>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, Object model, int position) {
                Trick trick = (Trick) model;
                TextView name = v.findViewById(R.id.name);
                TextView description = v.findViewById(R.id.description);

                name.setText(trick.getName().toString());
                description.setText(trick.getDescription().toString());


            }
        };
        list_View.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use FirebaseListAdapter you will need to import Firebase UI

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android

```
    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Realtime Database
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.3.2'

    // FirebaseUI for Cloud Firestore
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:4.3.2'
```

Also check this

https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#using-the-firebaserecycleradapter

Comment: Thank you very much for answer! Now i can import ```com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter``` and ```com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListOptions``` to my activity.